# How to create a batch file that checks if EXACTLY four specific files/folders exist in a folder?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, conditional-statements

I am writing a simple batch file that needs to perform its actions IFF (if and only if) exactly 2 files and 2 folders are present inside a specific folder.  The file and folder names must match exactly, which makes this relatively easy.

In pseudo-code this is:

```
IFF folder `FOO` contains (file `a.txt` AND file `b.txt` AND folder `f1` AND folder `f2`) THEN ...
```

BTW, the code after the `THEN ...` is all done.  No problem there.

Here is my code:

```
IF EXIST a.txt goto good1
goto done
:good1
IF EXIST b.txt goto good2
goto done
:good2
IF EXIST f1 goto good3
goto done
:good3
IF EXIST b.txt goto good4
goto done
:good4
echo requirements met
:done
```

I can use `IF EXIST` to handles the `IF` part of the `IFF` (IF and ONLY IF), but how can I ensure other files/folders are not present in folder `FOO`?

Ideally, I would like to keep this simple without creating temporary files caused by piping or `stdout` redirection to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method. We first count the files, then we test the files.

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
for /f %%i in ('dir /b') do set /a cnt+=1
if %cnt% equ 4 if exist f1 if exist f2 if exist dir1 if exist dir2 echo All Good!
```

and some light error generations:

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
for /f %%i in ('dir /b ^| findstr /v "%0"') do set /a cnt+=1
if not %cnt% equ 4 echo oops, too many files/dirs, I count %cnt% && goto :eof
if exist f1 if exist f2 if exist dir1 if exist dir2 echo All good && goto :eof
echo one or more files do not match your if statement
```

and one last method using `find` to not utilize a `for` loop.

```
@echo off
dir /b | find /c /v "" | findstr "\<4\>"
if errorlevel 1 echo oops, too many files/dirs, I count %cnt% && goto :eof
if exist f1 if exist f2 if exist dir1 if exist dir2 echo All good && goto :eof
echo one or more files do not match your if statement
```

---

Notes taken from this answer's comments:

1. `@echo off & set cnt=0` are integrated into a single line just to reduce the number of lines.  No other reason.
2. `findstr /v "%0"` is only needed if the batch file itself could be in the same folder, as that command simply excludes the batch file itself as part of the file count.